# Is the group of diffeomorphism $k$-transitve?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider for a connected manifold $M$, the group $G$ denotes the group of diffeomorphisms of $M$. It is easy to see that this group acts transitively on the whole manifold, i.e. for any two points $p,q\in M$, there always exist a diffeomorphism that takes $p$ to $q$.

Now suppose we have two sets $A=\{a_1,...a_k\}$ and $B=\{b_1,...b_k\}$ of points with each set consists of $k$ different points. Is it always possible for us to find a diffeomorphism that takes $A$ to $B$, i.e. it takes $a_i$ to $b_i$? If not, what is the maximal $k$ that works out fine?

Comment: seems like if you can connect a to b with a path avoiding a compact set K, then you can send a to b while fixing K pointwise

Comment: This is not always possible if $M = S^1$ and $k\geq 3$.  Otherwise it is.

Comment: @JasonDeVito $S^1$ is definitely $3$-transitive under diffeomorphism - the Möbius transformations are $3$-transitive. But the diffeomorphisms of $S^1$ are not $4$-transitive. On $M=\mathbb R$ they are not $3$-transitive.

Comment: @Thomas:  Oops.  I was thinking of orientation preserving maps, and I routinely forget non-compact manifolds exist.  Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: It is false in dimension 1 (order of point on the line), but true in any dimension $\geq 2$